# Python regex re.finditer weird behavior with match.end()

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the positions of patterns in a file, and I am using Python regex.  When I run the below code, several start positions are printed but only one end position, the one corresponding to the latest start position, is printed.  The bottom print statement is also only printed once.  Why is there not a `match.end()` value for every `match.start()` value? File is a .obj file.

```
import re
import binascii


def findByte(b,file):
    f = open(file, "rb").read()
    f = binascii.hexlify(f)
    regex = b + "(?=(?:[\\da-fA-F]{2})*$)"

    for match in (re.finditer(regex, f)):


        s = match.start()
        print("S" + str(s))

        e = match.end()
        print("E" + str(e))

        g = match.group()
        print(g)

        print ('String match "%s" at %d:%d' % (g, s, e))

findByte("ca","demo.obj")
```

When I run it, the below answers are printed.

```
S0
S64
S184
S252
E254
ca
String match "ca" at 252:254
```

If I instead write

```
def findByte(b,file):
    f = open(file, "rb").read()
    f = binascii.hexlify(f)
    regex = b + "(?=(?:[\\da-fA-F]{2})*$)"

    m = re.findall(regex,f)
    print(m)

findByte("ca","demo.obj")
```

The printed value is

```
['ca', 'ca', 'ca', 'ca']
```

Comment: Please provide an example `regex` and `f` so people can actually reproduce the behaviour. If I simply define `regex = r'\d\d'` and `f = '12 34 45 abc 34 def 1'` - it works exactly as you describe it should, so please provide the inputs, but also the outputs you're getting and how you expect them to be different

Comment: The problem is evidently with your regex - try it here https://regex101.com/r/XSQktS/1 and compare to https://regex101.com/r/XSQktS/2

Comment: When I use re.findall with the same regex to find the matches, it works.  (Unfortunately I cannot do it that way because I need the positions.) Why might that be?

Comment: Your result is impossible; it can't print an `S` output without a matching `E` as written (even if `match.end()` somehow returned the empty string or something, it would still print the `E`, which you don't see at all). I'm 99% certain the lines beginning with `e = match.end()` are dedented outside the `for` loop in your actual code, so they only run once, on the last `match` object, after the `for` loop exits.

Comment: If you want to know why one piece of code "works" and another doesn't, it's better to share both pieces of code, so people can see what you're talking about and what things look like when you think they "work"

Comment: I updated the post to include the entire contents of my file.  Where would the lines be dedented?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the actual code you pasted, it's clear you've committed the cardinal Python sin of mixing tabs and spaces, and it's biting you (try selecting the leading whitespace in your own code on this page; you'll see some of it is selected as blocks of four spaces at a time, while other parts have single space granularity). Your editor is showing you tabs as being equivalent to four spaces, but in the code you pasted, you have purely tab based indentation up through `print("S" + str(s))`, then four spaces followed by a tab as the indentation for subsequent lines.

Most such mixed indentation stuff is rejected by Python 3, but Python 2 is more flexible (it gives you the rope to hang yourself), which may be what is happening here (Python 2 is end of life as of the beginning of this year, so if you're writing new code, I'd suggest switching for this and many other reasons). Your code *looks* like it's all in the `for` loop, but most of it isn't.

Replace all your tabs with four space indents, and reconfigure your editor to *always* expand tabs to spaces in the future, so you aren't bit by this in the future; Python style is [consistent four space indents](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) with [no tabs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) for a reason.